# How can I parse one string to float in property template using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using the component `agm-map` and I need to pass to my component properties `[latitude]` and `[longitude]` coordinates in numeric. I'm receiving this value in string, but I need to convert.

I tried something like:

```
<agm-map 
     [mapTypeId]="'hybrid'"
     [latitude]="parseFloat(local.localLatitudeB)"
     [longitude]="parseFloat(local.localLongitudeB)"
     [zoom]="16"
     [disableDefaultUI]="false">

     ...
```

But this return:

> _co.parseFloat is not a function

One example of locallongitudeB that I receive from my front, but is in string: -47.410351923

Comment: You can try `[latitude]="+local.localLatitudeB"`. It should work

Answer (score 4):

In your ts file:

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
    parseFloat = parseFloat;

...
```

no change required in HTML.

Comment: So Clean and simple. Though about making a function and return the result, but this is so much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<agm-map 
     [mapTypeId]="'hybrid'"
     [latitude]="toFloat(local.localLatitudeB)"
     [longitude]="toFloat(local.localLongitudeB)"
     [zoom]="16"
     [disableDefaultUI]="false">

     ...
```

TS:

```
public toFloat(value: string): number {
   return parseFloat(value);
}
```

Comment: you don't need to wrap it in a new function, just make it available in the template by adding this to you class `parseFloat=parseFloat`